# How to use XmlElement.InnerXml WITHOUT any formatting?

Tags: c#, xml, formatting, saml, xmldocument

I need to communicate with a WebService through XML. This service is using a saml:Assertion to authenticate the connection. I can communicate with the server, but the validation always fails. I searched for hours what the problem is, because when I use soapUI with the exact same parameters and saml ticket, it works. I tried to "manually" remove any formatting from the saml:Assertion because it was signed, so with a single-byte change, it won't work anymore.

Here's my code:

```
// Insert saml:Assertion string into soapenv:Header
private static void InsertSAML(ref XmlDocument soapXML, ref XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr, string saml)
{
    // Remove all formatting
    saml = saml.Replace("\r", "");
    saml = saml.Replace("\n", "");
    while(saml.IndexOf("  ") > -1)
    {
        saml = saml.Replace("  ", " ");
    }
    saml = saml.Replace("> <", "><");
    saml = saml.Replace("\" />", "\"/>");

    XmlElement soapHeader = (XmlElement)soapXML.SelectSingleNode("//soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Header/wsse:Security", nsmgr);
    if (soapHeader == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Can't find \"//soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Header/wsse:Security\"");
    }

    soapHeader.InnerXml += saml;
}
```

But it seems like when I use `soapHeader.InnerXml += saml;` it causes some kind of formatting. A whitespace will appear before the closing tags of elements without inner content:

So, I need to add this:

```
<dsig:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
```

But in the final XML looks like this, even if I replaced these occurences before inserting:

```
<dsig:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
```

How can I get rid of this behaviour?

Comment: Why are you assuming it is the formatting that is failing?  Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare the soapUI response with your application response.  Them make you application look like the soapUI.  Start by comparing 1st request and modifying your c# code so the headers are the same as soapUI.

Comment: It must be the formatting. The request from soapUI and my C# code has the exact same headers and body, except the space before closing ( /> ) single tags.

Comment: What are you calling the formatting if the headers and body are the same?  Is the first response the same?  Are both using http 1.0?  Are you getting a 200 done status? I would think it would be a timing issue if the data is exactly the same.  The http is using tcp as the transport layer and there could be a tcp disconnect.  but I don't think so.  It is more like you have two connections open at the same time and the server isn't allowing the 2nd connection.

Comment: I got a clear response from the WebService. There are no connection issues, the request is sent, and the response is received from the server I want to access. The problem is, that I got an error message (a coded response from that server) that my saml is not valid. And that's true, my saml:Assertion can't be valid with additional whitespaces in it. The saml is a signed fiingerprint, and if a byte is modified, it isn't valid anymore. I just want to know how to insert it without additional whitespaces into my xml.

Comment: The signing has to be done after the all editing to the body is made.  Space and returns should get encrypted and then decrypted and shouldn't make any difference.  So I don't know why you are trying to remove spaces.  There is something in the encryption (signing) method you are using in c# is different from the decryption the server is using.

Comment: The whole process works like this: I send a request to the server with simple http authentication, username and password. If the authentication is OK, the server returns a saml:Assertion which I can (and must) use for further requests, as it is, without changing a byte. I try to do this, in fact, it doesn't matter if I remove spaces or not with that function, this is just to make sure that the saml works even if it was pasted from a source where it was displayed as formatted xml. The problem is still that C# add whitespaces into it when I paste it into the request.

Comment: I don't need to "sign" my message with it's contents, I only need to insert the saml:Assertion I got from the previus response to my request, without changing it. And that's the pont I got stuck with C#, because it always insert spaces into it, so the server of course can't validate it. This is not the saml I got from the previous response, this is 6 bytes longer.

Comment: Lets fix the root cause and not try to patch.  What code are you reading from the response and how are you adding to request?

Comment: Just for information:
Internally, a XMLWriter is used in the end to create the valid formatted xml string. This writer can be instructed to preserve whitespaces, but the writer performs this only for the content of nodes, not the structure/attributes. If you really want to have your whitespaces preserved/not inserted, you will need to create your own XMLWriter and use it to add your text to the XDocument. I would not recommend that as any later interaction with the document may add the whitespaces again.

Comment: I solved it. As you said, XmlWriter interaction will cause this again and again, so I removed the whitespaces later on, when I parse the xml content into my httpWebRequest. This way I can treat the xml as a plain string, remove the unnecessary (and problem causing) formattings that XmlWriter added, and post the request. It feels a bit like an ugly workaround, but it's good enough for now, I can finally get real data from the server without any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said, the problem was with the additional bytes XmlDocument added to my xml when I append content to the InnerXml. I tried so hard to remove all formatting, and it was a good direction. But instead of "un-formatting" the saml:Assertion part, I magaged to un-format the whole request body, right before it was sent to the service. And now it works. I call this method right before sending the request:

```
// Insert XML to request body
private static void InsertSoapEnvelopeIntoWebRequest(XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml, HttpWebRequest webRequest)
{
    using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
    using (var xmlTextWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter))
    using (Stream stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
    {
        // Get XML contents as string
        soapEnvelopeXml.WriteTo(xmlTextWriter);
        xmlTextWriter.Flush();
        string str = stringWriter.GetStringBuilder().ToString();

        // Remove all formatting
        str = str.Replace("\r", "");
        str = str.Replace("\n", "");
        while (str.IndexOf("  ") > -1)
        {
            str = str.Replace("  ", " ");
        }
        str = str.Replace("> <", "><");
        str = str.Replace("\" />", "\"/>");

        // Write the unbeutified text to the request stream
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(UTF8Encoding.Default.GetBytes(str));
        ms.WriteTo(stream);
    }
}
```